# Can someone tell my why am i getting this error in mysql workbench while forward engineering?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I created the ER diagram for the student management system and click the forward engineering and go through the steps in dialog box. But it shows up error message like this.

```
   Executing SQL script in server
   ERROR: Error 1075: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
 SQL Code:
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `SLIOP`.`course`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SLIOP`.`course` (
      `courseNo` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `courseID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      `course_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
      `course_type` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      `content_type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      `lecturer_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
      `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
      `fee` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
      `no_classes` INT NOT NULL,
      `no_students` INT NOT NULL,
      `requirement` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
      `lecturerID` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`courseID`),
      INDEX `fk_course_academic_staff1_idx` (`lecturerID` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_course_academic_staff1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`lecturerID`)
        REFERENCES `SLIOP`.`academic_staff` (`lecturerID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB

    SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed

    Fetching back view definitions in final form.
    Nothing to fetch
```

Can someone tell my where is the error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on PRIMARY KEY

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SLIOP`.`course` (
  `courseNo` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `courseID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `course_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `course_type` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `content_type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `lecturer_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `fee` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `no_classes` INT NOT NULL,
  `no_students` INT NOT NULL,
  `requirement` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `lecturerID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`courseNo`),
  INDEX `fk_course_academic_staff1_idx` (`lecturerID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_course_academic_staff1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`lecturerID`)
    REFERENCES `SLIOP`.`academic_staff` (`lecturerID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```